# Can a phrasal verb be considered an expression?

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs, terminology

I know that 'to bang on about something' is a phrasal verb but can it also be considered an expression?

Comment: It's best called a verbal idiom rather than a phrasal verb, a misnomer, since it's only "bang" that's a verb, not "bang on".

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely:

> **expression**
>
> 3. a word or phrase, especially an idiomatic one, used to convey an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.